# Swift: Setting Different Navigation Bar Buttons for Different Tabs

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, navigationbar, tabbar

I created a custom UITabBarController with 5 tabs in Swift 3.0. I've been trying to set different navigation bar items for certain tabs, but it's not working well.

Situation: I put codes that would change the Navigation Bar Buttons in each tab's viewDidLoad().

```
//The customized Tab Bar controller instance. Contained in each of the tabs.
var mainController: TabBarController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ... more code
    setupNavBar()
    // ... more code
}

func setupNavBar() {
    // ... more code
    mainController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: friendsImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleFindFriends))
    // ... more code
}
```

Problem: Let's say Tab #1 is supposed to have NavBarButton A and Tab #2 is supposed to have NavBarButton B. 
When I switch from Tab #1 to Tab #2, the code works fine; the NavBarButton changes from A to B. 
However, when I click on Tab #1, the NavBarButton still remains B.

How can I make it so that the navigation bar buttons change accordingly even when I click on a tab I was on previously?

Comment: Let create one TabBarController and (NavigationController > ViewController) for each Tab. So you can add barButtonItem for each ViewController.

Comment: I've added the code to my answer, please, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution XD
In TabBarController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Original code to set up tabs

    //Code I added:
    for i in 0...4 {
        tabBar.items?[i].tag = i
    }
}
//Code I added:
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    //Code to run when a certain tab is selected
}
```

Still, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you embed a `UITabBarController` (or it's subclass) into a `UIViewController`. This is wrong because in this case you tend to make the view controller generic which is usually a bad practice.

Instead I would suggest to change hierarchy of view controller to what you see on the image below.

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you do it in code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

        // first tab
        let firstViewController = UIViewController()
        _ = firstViewController.view
        firstViewController.title = "First"
        let firstNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)

        // sets a specific button ("Friends") on a navigation bar for the first screen
        firstViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Friends", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        // second tab
        let secondViewController = UIViewController()
        _ = secondViewController.view
        secondViewController.title = "Second"
        let secondNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController)

        // sets a specific button ("Photos") on a navigation bar for the second screen
        secondViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Photos", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        // embeds the navigation controllers into the tab bar controller
        tabBarController.viewControllers = [firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController]

        // creates a window with the tab bar controller inside
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats the image of my answer, nice work @Artem Stepanenko